# Intrinsic content size of button with text only

Tags: ios

I have a uibutton, i want to set text dynamically at run time with padding top: 10, bottom 10 and left: 10 and right: 10, once i set text button title cliped. Any one can provide solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must be attentive to fontSize of the button. Setting text programmatically doesn't automatically fits the text. Following code will help you.

```
//Swift
let btnLabel = yourButton.titleLabel
btnLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

//Objective C
UILabel *btnLabel = yourButton.titleLabel;
btnLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

> Happy Coding <3